# Try-Catch statement in Swift completing Try statement but printing Catch error

Tags: ios, swift, try-catch

I am executing the following code to update my local store:

```
do {
    // Update our normalized local store immediately for a responsive UI
    try transaction?.update(query: PostsQuery()) { (data: inout PostsQuery.Data) in
        data.allPosts?.append(PostsQuery.Data.AllPost.init(id: uniqueId, title: mutation.title, author: mutation.author, content: mutation.content, version: 0))
    }
} catch {
    print("Error updating the cache with optimistic response.")
}
```

The append is correctly adding an item to the array, which would indicate to me that the try is working.  However the console prints out the "Error updating the cache with optimistic response." message.

My understanding was that only if the try statement was unsuccessful the catch statement would print?  Not sure how the completion of the try statement is being run and also the catch statement is bring printed?

Comment: Why do you print a meaningless literal string rather than the **actual** error?

Comment: this is the code template from an AWS appsync tutorial

Comment: There is nothing to stop the function from invoking the completion handler and then throwing. Printing the error may help you understand what is happening

Comment: I see.  It's my lack of understanding of the Try-Catch.  I took Vadian's advice and changed to "catch let error as NSError" printed the error and on my way to trying to resolve it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to print the details of the error instead.

```
do {
    // Update our normalized local store immediately for a responsive UI
    try transaction?.update(query: PostsQuery()) { (data: inout PostsQuery.Data) in
        data.allPosts?.append(PostsQuery.Data.AllPost.init(id: uniqueId, title: mutation.title, author: mutation.author, content: mutation.content, version: 0))
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

The catch block will only be called when an error is thrown inside the do block, so you need to see what the error is and handle that case